# How to make a design "loose coupling"?

Tags: java, position, coupling, cohesion

I'm making a simple 3D CAD software. in the class diagram, many objects need to distinguish with others by (x,y,z). I create a class so-called "Position", but the problem is it looks highly-coupling because many classese work with position.
Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of things are going to depend on Position() so you'll have to think carefully about if it should be mutable (or you make a new one when it changes) and be careful not to add too many extra methods to it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem per se if a type is used by many other types. In your case, graphical objects obviously (usually) have a position so the coupling looks natural and reasonable from the perspective of the domain model.

Also, the Position class is probably going to be a fairly low-level class whose interface (and probably implementation too) is not going to change very often in the long run. So there is not much chance of such changes breaking client code.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say after 12 years that your design is not bad. Assuming that the positioning logic of your classes shall be called from outside, all your classes need to have and offer this logic. So it is part of the interface and  you must bring the functionalities in. And this means, you must depend on it and there is a coupling. The coupling is not between your objects. So it is not as bad.

But there are always alternatives. It is known that inheritance establishes a very tight coupling. Consider for example that the positioning logic is only called internally in your class. Then you don't have any benefit in inheritance. You could as well have another class (let us call it Position). And instead of deriving from this class, you integrate an object of this class. And whenever you want to do something with the position, you call the corresponding methods of this object.

This alternative looks like a nonsense change. Why should you do this? But let us have a look at the consequences. Assume you have a class Circle. Circle has such a position object as proposed above. (By the way, see the wording "has a position" instead of "is a position". The "object-and-composition" solution seems to be quite natural.) Somewhere in a file X of your code you may have created such a Circle. And now you decide you change the positioning logic. In X you don't have to worry that this has a side effect, because the interface of Circle has not changed. It is just one object inside of Circle that has changed. That is just an implementation detail. In contrast if you would have used inheritance, you cannot just change the base class without looking if this has a negative effect to X. So this "object-and-composition" solution has actually reduced the coupling between X and the positioning logic.

You can even reduce the coupling further. With the object-and-composition solution, whenever you change the positioning logic, you have to check all your classes if this has an effect. But what about using an interface for Position. Your classes don't see an object of a type Position, but an object  that fullfils an interface Position. And the actual positioning logic implements this interface. This way most of your classes' code has no dependency to the implementation of the positioning logic.

That is not the end of the game. There is still a coupling, because your classes must somehow create the position objects. So at least the constructor must go into detail and for example pass x,y,z. But what if you use something like a factory for this purpose, so that your objects just get the position without even knowing how these have been created. Then you are absolutely flexible. You can use your classes in completely different situations. For example in a two dimensional coordinate system. There is no coupling between your positioning logic and your classes any more.

I hope you see that all these options exist. I suppose in your example this is a bit over-engineered. But your question was how to reduce the coupling. And there are always ways. Combinations are of course possible. For example you can have the object-and-composition and make the position object public in your base class. But then I would ask if not inheritance would have been the better option?